# React query `data` is `null` due to async token check

Tags: reactjs, react-query

This is my useQuery function

```
export default function useSearch(searchParams) {
  const { getToken } = useAuth();
  return {
    ...useQuery({
      queryKey: ["journal-search", searchParams],
      queryFn: async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
          `${apiUrl}/api/journal/search?query=${searchParams}`,
          {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${await getToken()}` },
          }
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
      },
      enabled: Boolean(searchParams.length),
      keepPreviousData: true,
      staleTime: 1000,
    }),
  };
}
```

For some reason, `data` is `null` and `isLoading` is never `true`. I suspect it has to do with this: `headers: { Authorization:` Bearer ${await getToken()} `},` perhaps this breaks react query in some way. I'm not sure how to structure my code prevent `null` or `undefined`. Using `placeholderData` has yielded buggy results, I still get null on occasion.

Comment: Could you please check the network tab on dev tools and tell what is the response of your request?